# Why dont they display in the ViewGroup?

Tags: android, viewgroup

I just use a subclass to extends the ViewGroup and addView() ,but the screen  display only one.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    FlowLayout fl = (FlowLayout) findViewById(R.id.flow_scroll);
    for (int i = 0; i < courseNames.length; i++) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.score_item, fl, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.courseName);
        tv.setText(courseNames[i]);
        fl.addView(view);
    }
```

this is the subclass

```
public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup
```

Comment: can you show me the xml for R.id.flow_scroll and R.layout.score_item?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.example.widget.FlowLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/flow_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.widget.FlowLayout>

</ScrollView>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/courseName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

Comment: Did you implement `onMeasure()` and on `onLayout()`?